A system of ordinary differential equations on the sphere involving the cross product
Consider the following o.d.e. system on $p,v:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
\begin{align*}
p' &= (\cos (at+b))(p\times v)\\
v' &=(\sin (at+b)) (p\times v)
\end{align*}
with orthonormal initial conditions, i.e. $p(0)=p_0,v(0)=v_0\in \mathbb{S}^2$ with $\langle p_0,v_0\rangle =0$, and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ constants.

Does this system admit existence and uniqueness of solutions?
If so, is it possible to solve it explicitly?

Notice that any solution will automatically satisfy $\langle p,v\rangle\equiv 0$ (to see this, simply derivate $\langle p,v\rangle$, use the equations and initial conditions). Similarly, we must have $\langle p,p\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle=1$. Therefore, $p$ can be seen as a curve on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $v$ as a unitary vector field along $p$ (since $\langle p,v\rangle=0\iff v \in T_p\mathbb{S}^2$).
In the particular case $a=b=0$, we must have $v'\equiv 0$ and hence $v\equiv v_0$. For $p$ we must have then $p'=p\times v_0$. Actually, since the solution must satisfy $\langle p,v_0\rangle =0$ with $\langle p,p\rangle=1$, we can conclude that $p$ describes a great circle in $\mathbb{S}^2$.
I wasn't able to do much for the general case.
I would appreciate any help and references on this type of system.

It seems when we introduce the variables $w=p\times v$ and $x=(p,v,w)^T$ then we obtain a linear system $x'=A(t)x$ of differential equations.

Reparametrization.
Since you dealt with the existence and uniqueness of the solution to the considered system of ODEs, I will focus on its resolution. To begin with, let's rename a few variables for convenience : $e_1 = p$, $e_2 = v$ and $e_3 = p \times v$, as well as $\theta = at+b$. It is to be noted that the equation of motion for $e_3$ can be deduced from the ones for $e_1$ and $e_2$, because $\dot{e}_3 = \dot{e}_1 \times e_2 + e_1 \times \dot{e}_2$ by the product rule, which allows us to rewrite the present problem as the following "closed" system :
$$
\begin{cases}
   \dot{e}_1 =  e_3\cos\theta \\
   \dot{e}_2 =  e_3\sin\theta \\
   \dot{e}_3 = -e_1\cos\theta - e_2\sin\theta \,e_2
\end{cases},
\quad\quad
\begin{cases}
   e_1(0) = p_0 \\
   e_2(0) = v_0 \\
   e_3(0) = p_0 \times v_0 
\end{cases}
$$
or $\dot{X} = AX$ in matrix notation, with $X = (e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
           0 &           0 & \cos\theta \\
           0 &           0 & \sin\theta \\
 -\cos\theta & -\sin\theta &          0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It has to be highlighted, as you did partially, that $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ form an orthonormal system on the unit sphere $\Bbb{S}^2$. Indeed, since $e_3 = e_1 \times e_2$ is perpendicular to $e_1$ and $e_2$ by construction, it is easy to check that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \langle e_i,e_j \rangle = \langle \dot{e}_i,e_j \rangle + \langle e_i,\dot{e}_j \rangle = 0 \;\forall i,j = 1,2,3$, hence $\langle e_i(t),e_j(t) \rangle = \langle e_i(0),e_j(0) \rangle = \delta_{ij} \;\forall t$.
When $a = 0$.
In the case where $\theta = b = const$, the matrix $A$ is time-independent, hence a mere system of coupled linear equations of motion with constant coefficients, which can be solved with your favorite method among the numerous available ones. You will end up with sinusoidal functions. Indeed, one deduces from $\ddot{e}_3 = -e_3$ that $e_3$ is a harmonic oscillator with unit frequency, i.e. $e_3(t) = A\cos t + B\sin t$, where the constants of integration $A$ and $B$ are have to be determined from the boundary conditions. Finally, you need to integrate this result in order to find $e_1$ and $e_2$, hence in the end :
$$
\begin{cases}
   e_1(t) = -p_0 \times v_0 \sin t - (p_0\cos b + v_0\sin b)(1 - \cos t) + p_0 \\
   e_2(t) = -p_0 \times v_0 \sin t - (p_0\cos b + v_0\sin b)(1 - \cos t) + v_0 \\
   e_3(t) = +p_0 \times v_0 \cos t - (p_0\cos b + v_0\sin b)\sin t
\end{cases}
$$
When $a \neq 0$.
With non-constant $\theta$, the matrix $A$ remains time-dependent and the resolution becomes far more tricky, unless the matrices $A(s)$ and $A(t)$ commute for all times $s,t$ (or, equivalently, $A$ commutes with its antiderivative), which is not the case here, unfortunately. You may refer to this answer of mine, where such cases are discussed briefly.
Nonetheless, in the present case, we might exploit the fact that $A$ acts on the sphere $\Bbb{S}^2$ and is thus somewhat related to the 3D rotation group $SO(3)$. More concretely, one has $A(t) = -L_x\sin\theta + L_y\cos\theta$, where
$$
L_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\;
L_y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
\text{ and }\,
L_z = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
are the generators of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Now, recalling that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{f(t)B} = f'(t)B\,e^{f(t)B}$ for a time-independent operator $B$ (see here), we are able to conclude that the solution to the initial system of ODEs is given formally by $X(t) = e^{(L_x\cos\theta)/a}e^{(L_y\sin\theta)/a}X(0)$, with
$$
\exp\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}L_x\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
   0 & \cos\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right) \\ 
   0 & \sin\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\exp\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{a}L_y\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
   \cos\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{a}\right) & 0 & \sin\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{a}\right) \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
   -\sin\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{a}\right) & 0 & \cos\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{a}\right)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I let you finish and compute the final (and messy) matrix multiplications.

Some system properties. Making
$$
\cases{
p'\cdot v = \cos(a t + b)(p\times v)\cdot v\\
v'\cdot p = \sin(a t + b)(p\times v)\cdot p
}
$$
after adding, we get $p\cdot v = C_0$ and analogously
$$
\cases{
\|p\| = C_p\\
\|v\| = C_v\\
\|v\times p\| = C_c
}
$$
Also
$$
\cases{
p'\times v = \cos(a t + b)(p\times v)\times v\\
p\times v' = \sin(a t + b)p\times (p\times v)
}
$$
but
$$
\cases{
(p\times v)\times v = (v\cdot p)v-(v\cdot v)p\\
p\times (p\times v) = (p\cdot v)p-(p\cdot p)v
}
$$
now choosing $C_0 = 0, C_p=1, C_v=1$ in the initial conditions, we have
$$
\cases{
(p\times v)\times v = -p\\
p\times (p\times v) = -v
}
$$
and then
$$
(p\times v)' = -(\cos(a t + b)p+\sin(a t + b)v)
$$
and consequently
$$
\|(p\times v)'\| = 1
$$
Redefining now $\{p=p_1, v = p_2\}$ with
$$
p_i^T = (\cos\phi_i\sin\gamma_i,\cos\phi_i\cos\gamma_i,\sin\phi_i)
$$
and the system of odes after considering the second and third components of each $p_i'$, can be reduced to
$$
\cases{
\phi_1' = \cos(a t + b)\cos\phi_2\sin(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)\\
\gamma_1' = \cos(a t + b)\left(\sin\phi_2-\cos\phi_2\cos(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)\tan\phi_1\right)\\
\phi_2'=\sin(a t + b)\cos\phi_1\sin(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)\\
\gamma_2'=-\sin(a t + b)(\sin\phi_1-\cos\phi_1\cos(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)\tan\phi_2)
}
$$
Follows a plot showing $p_1$ in blue and $p_2$ in red for the parameters and initial conditions:
$a = 1, b = 1, \phi_1(0) = 0, \gamma_1(0)= \pi/5, \phi_2(0)=\pi/2-\epsilon, \gamma_2(0)=\pi/3$ with $\epsilon = 10^{-12}$


I'm posting an answer myself for the existence and uniqueness of solutions part.
The system can be written as
$$X'=f(t,X),$$
with $X=(p,v):I\to \mathbb{R}^6$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^6\to \mathbb{R}^6$ given by
$$f(t,(p,v))= (\cos (at+b) (p\times v), \sin (at+v) (p\times v)).$$
Now, since $f$ is smooth, it is in particular continuous and all of its partial derivatives in $(p,v)$ - the "spatial" variables - are also continuous. This guarantees existence and uniqueness of solutions for an open neighborhood around $t=0$, once provided initial values $p(0)=p_0$ and $v(0)=v_0$.
Also, since $f$ is well defined on $\Omega:= \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^6$, we must have that the maximal solution $X=(p,v):I\to\mathbb{R}^6 $ is defined for every parameter $t$, i.e. we must have $I = \mathbb{R}$. This is so because $(t,X(t))$ must get close to the boundary $\partial \Omega$ when $t$ goes to the upper or lower bound of $I$. However, as already mentioned on the question, the solution $X$ lies on $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2$ and therefore it is bounded. Therefore, we can't have boundedness (above or below) on $t$.
